# Some balls are flood in to the floor

Tags: actionscript-3

The problem is when i have 2 or more balls on stage,some balls are bouncing perfect and some other are sink in floors.
The floors on stage are already on stage.
Is that a drawing problem or its something else?

```
    stop();
//ARRAYS
var ballArray:Array = new Array();

//ADD BALLS
var mediumBall1f2:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f2);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f2);
mediumBall1f2.ballX = 3;
mediumBall1f2.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f2.x = 300;
mediumBall1f2.y = 250;
mediumBall1f2.width = 120;
mediumBall1f2.height = 120;

var mediumBall1f3:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f3);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f3);
mediumBall1f3.ballX = -3;
mediumBall1f3.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f3.x = 200;
mediumBall1f3.y = 350;
mediumBall1f3.width = 140;
mediumBall1f3.height = 140;

var mediumBall1f4:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f4);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f4);
mediumBall1f4.ballX = -3;
mediumBall1f4.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f4.x = 300;
mediumBall1f4.y = 250;
mediumBall1f4.width = 50;
mediumBall1f4.height = 50;

var mediumBall1f5:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f5);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f5);
mediumBall1f5.ballX = -3;
mediumBall1f5.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f5.x = 400;
mediumBall1f5.y = 350;
mediumBall1f5.width = 80;
mediumBall1f5.height = 80;

var mediumBall1f6:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f6);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f6);
mediumBall1f6.ballX = 3;
mediumBall1f6.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f6.x = 400;
mediumBall1f6.y = 320;
mediumBall1f6.width = 30;
mediumBall1f6.height = 30;

var mediumBall1f7:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f7);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f7);
mediumBall1f7.ballX = 3;
mediumBall1f7.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f7.x = 400;
mediumBall1f7.y = 230;

var mediumBall1f8:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f8);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f8);
mediumBall1f8.ballX = 3;
mediumBall1f8.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f8.x = 400;
mediumBall1f8.y = 240;

var mediumBall1f9:Ball = new Ball  ;
ballArray.push(mediumBall1f9);
this.addChild(mediumBall1f9);
mediumBall1f9.ballX = 3;
mediumBall1f9.ballY = 8;
mediumBall1f9.x = 400;
mediumBall1f9.y = 110;


//FLOOR
var downArray:Array = new Array();

for (var dA:int = numChildren - 1; dA>= 0; dA--)
{
    var childdA:DisplayObject = getChildAt(dA);
    if (childdA.name == "downfloor")
    {
        downArray.push(MovieClip(childdA));
    }
}

var upArray:Array = new Array();

for (var uA:int = numChildren - 1; uA>= 0; uA--)
{
    var childuA:DisplayObject = getChildAt(uA);
    if (childuA.name == "upfloor")
    {
        upArray.push(MovieClip(childuA));
    }
}

var rightArray:Array = new Array();

for (var rA:int = numChildren - 1; rA>= 0; rA--)
{
    var childrA:DisplayObject = getChildAt(rA);
    if (childrA.name == "rightfloor")
    {
        rightArray.push(MovieClip(childrA));
    }
}

var leftArray:Array = new Array();

for (var lA:int = numChildren - 1; lA>= 0; lA--)
{
    var childlA:DisplayObject = getChildAt(lA);
    if (childlA.name == "leftfloor")
    {
        leftArray.push(MovieClip(childlA));
    }
}

//USE ONCE
stageclear.visible = false;
stageclear.gotoAndStop(1);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ballLoop);
function ballLoop(evt:Event)
{
    //BALL
    for (var j = 0; j<ballArray.length; j++)
    {

        var ball:Ball = ballArray[j] as Ball;
        ball.ballY--;
        ball.y -=  ball.ballY;
        ball.x -=  ball.ballX;
        if (player.hitTestObject(ball))
        {

            ball.y = 600;
        }
        if(ball.x - ball.width/2 < 0)
        {
            ball.ballX = -3;
        }
        if(ball.x + ball.width/2 > 800)
        {
            ball.ballX = 3;
        }
        if(ball.y + ball.height/2 > 384.45)
        {
            ball.ballY = 20;
        }
        if(ball.y - ball.height/2 < 0)
        {
            ball.ballY = -2;
        }
            for (var d = 0; d<downArray.length; d++)
            {
                var down:DownFloor = downArray[d] as DownFloor;
                if (ball.hitTestObject(down))
                {
                    ball.ballY = 20;
                }
            }
            for (var r = 0; r<rightArray.length; r++)
            {
                    var right:RightFloor = rightArray[r] as RightFloor;
                    if (ball.hitTestObject(right))
                    {
                        ball.ballX = 3;
                    }
            }
            for (var l = 0; l<leftArray.length; l++)
            {
                var left:LeftFloor = leftArray[l] as LeftFloor;
                if (ball.hitTestObject(left))
                {
                    ball.ballX = -3;
                }
            }
            for (var u = 0; u<upArray.length; u++)
            {
                var up:UpFloor = upArray[u] as UpFloor;
                if (ball.hitTestObject(up))
                {
                    ball.ballY = -2;
                }
            }
        if (ball.y >= 600)
        {
            ball.parent.removeChild(ball);
            ballArray.splice(j,1);
        }
        if (ballArray.length <= 0)
        {
            stageclear.visible = true;
            stageclear.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
    }
    if(stageclear.currentFrame == stageclear.totalFrames)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ballLoop);
        MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which balls are sinking into the floor? After they sink into the floor, do they bounce back off the floor? Or do they get stuck?

Comment: Im guessing your problem has to do with hitTest. It's very common for programmers to miss the fact that the ball will be rendered once while hitTest is true, so there will be a visible overlap. The only way I know to fix this is to use your own custom collision detection.

Comment: the balls are bouncing again.. they just miss a little from hittest. if i use hittestpoint i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

### the reason this is happening

This is happening because `hitTest` is only true if the MCs overlap. If you could look more closely, you'd see that this happens to all of the balls (it's just more apparent with some than others).

### the only fix that I know of

Make your own collision detection.

It could look like this:

```
function collisionTest (mc1:MovieClip,mc2:MovieClip){
    // test if mc1 is going to hit mc2's left side *on the next frame*
    if (mc1.x + mc1._xSpeed + mc1.width>= mc2.x){
        mc1.x = mc2.x; // this may cause a momentary pause... The ball may seem to stick to the wall for a frame... If this is a problem let me know and I'll show you how to fix that
        mc1._xSpeed *= -1;
    }
    // test if mc1 is going to hit top edge of mc2 *on the next frame*
    if (mc1.y + mc1._ySpeed + mc1.height >= mc2.y){
         mc1.y = mc2.y; // same possible sticking here
         mc1._ySpeed *= -1;
    }
}
```

### note

- For this to work, the registration point for the MCs should be top-left (which is the default).
- Also, my code only works for object 1 moving down, colliding with the top of object2 or object 1 moving right colliding with left side of object 2.
- `_xSpeed` and `_ySpeed` are things you will need to add as properties to your ball class and use that property to dictate motion of the balls. **This is the key**: it allows you to look ahead, into the future, and see if the ball is *going to* hit the wall on the next frame, and if it is, run the result of collision *now*, instead of *after* they overlap.

You'll need to add similar code for if the ball is moving left and you want it to detect collision with the right edge of a wall. Also for if the ball is moving up and you want to detect collision with the bottom of a wall

Don't forget to include an adjustment for the width of the wall or the width of the ball (since we are using the registration point which is top left of the bounding box)